# Webworker multiple threads

Tags: javascript, service-worker, web-worker

if I need to do the same task multiple time, did I need to create multiple workers, or the same worker can be use multiple time asynchronous like a server?

```
var chunks = [];
       var decryptedChucnkFnc = function (args) {
           // My builder blob job here
      }
      // determine the number of maximum worker to use
      var maxWorker = 5;
      if (totalParts < maxWorker) {
        maxWorker = totalParts;
      }
      for (var iw = 0; iw < maxWorker; iw++) {

        eval('var w' + iw + ' = new Worker("decryptfile.min.js")');
        var wo = eval("w" + iw);
        var item = blobs.pop();
        wo.postMessage(MyObjectPassToTheFile);
        wo.onmessage = decryptedChucnkFnc;
      }
```

Did I need to create the same worker instance 5 times, our just need to call a same worker 5 times?

Comment: Just send 5 messages to the same webworker. It's a *worker*, not a one-off *task*.

Comment: And even if you want to instantiate multiple workers (parallel processing?), don't ever use `eval` for this! Put them into an array instead of having dynamic enumerated variable names.

Comment: But an array with multiple instance of the same worker will be more performant than call 5 times the same worker?

Comment: Depends on your workload. Workers do have a quite high startup-cost, so if you do not fully capitalise one there's no point in instantiating more. Only if your workers crunch data at 100% cpu load you might benefit from having more.